# JBox2D - Find collision coordinates

Tags: java, box2d, physics, collision, jbox2d

I'm writing a program in Java using JBox2D. I need to find the exact point of collision between two textures, if and when they collide.

I have the code to determine if a collision happens, and  can obviously just call the collision object ID to determine which textures are colliding.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to grab the actual coordinates of the collision itself. I read the documentation, but it is very complicated and does not address this issue directly.

Here's my code:

```
import org.jbox2d.callbacks.ContactImpulse;
import org.jbox2d.callbacks.ContactListener;
import org.jbox2d.collision.Manifold;
import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.Fixture;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.Contact;


public class MyContactListener implements ContactListener{


    //When they start to collide
    public void beginContact(Contact c) {

    System.out.println("CONTACT");

    Fixture fa = c.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fb = c.getFixtureB();

    Vec2 posA = fa.getBody().getPosition();
    Vec2 posB = fb.getBody().getPosition();



}

public void endContact(Contact c) {

}

public void preSolve(Contact c, Manifold m) {}

public void postSolve(Contact c, ContactImpulse ci){}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know where the collision happened, you should know that sometimes there is not only one point of collision, but a set of points.

[image: extracted from manual]

(Image extracted from [this manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf))

As the above manual says:

> Box2D has functions to compute contact points for overlapping shapes. [...] These points [...] groups them into a manifold structure. [...]
>
> Normally you don't need to compute contact manifolds directly, however you will likely use the result produced in the simulation.[...] If you need this data, it is usually best to use the [WorldManifold](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/updating/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/collision/WorldManifold.java?r=349) structure [...].

You can access it inside the `Contact c` class:

```
public void beginContact(Contact c) {
    System.out.println("CONTACT");
    
    WorldManifold worldmanifold;
    worldmanifold = c.getWorldManifold();
    
    for(Vec2 point : worldmanifold.points){
        System.out.println("Contact at : [" + point.x + ", " + point.y "]");
    }
}
```

**Important**: I have never used this library (JBox2D), however, I'm familiar with it (since libGDX apparently use a similar one (Box2D)). Also, I don't know if JBox2D is Box2D (the C++ one) for Java, and if JBox2D and Box2D (the libGDX one) are related at all. So maybe some methods can change (`point.x` could be `point.getX()`).

You could check [this site](http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8005) too, but this is for C++ (I use their answer to answer you).